# TypeError: replace() argument 2 must be str, not datetime.date

Tags: visual-studio-code, typeerror

Letter = '''DEAR <|NAME>
CONGRATULATIONS !
YOU ARE SELECTED FOR THE JOB
DATE : <|DATE> '''

name = input ("Enter your Name : ")
today = date.today()

Letter = Letter.replace("<|NAME>" , name)
Letter = Letter.replace("<|DATE>" , today)

print(Letter)

```
enter code here
```

Comment: What language is that?

Comment: I'd simply listen to the error: `replace` wants a string to insert, and you gave it the return of `date.today()`, which apparently returns a `datetime.date`.